# problem on creating a scrollbar in toggle_menu_frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

when I add a scroll bar to the toggle_menu_frame with the basic steps
1-creating a canvas and toggle_menu_frame

```
toggle_menu_fm = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightgray", borderwidth=3, relief="raised")
        toggle_menu_fm.place(x=145, y=0, height=920, width=800)
        canvas1 = tk.Canvas(toggle_menu_fm)
        canvas1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

2-creating the scollbar

```
        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(toggle_menu_fm, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas1.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
```

3-Configuring the canvas

```
canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
```

4-creating an other frame

```
frame = tk.Frame(canvas1)
```

4-creating  a window in the frame and binding the canvas

```
 canvas1.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor="nw")

        canvas1.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
```

5-this is the on_cnfigure function

```
def on_configure(event):
    global canvas1
    canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
```

so on  the toggle_menu_frame there is a rectangle that is aprrearing on the left that is pusing other element on it and the scroll bar is not working

I tries to chenge the values in the fill and the values in Side for each element but no result

Comment: Please consider combining all of those blocks of code into a single [mcve].

Comment: i just want to explain all the steps I did I apologise

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There is nothing in the internal `frame`, so the scrollbar will not be activated because the height of the frame is shorter than the canvas.